# 2014 USAMO #6, analytic number theory

Tags: contest-math, analytic-number-theory

Prove that there is a constant $c > 0$ with the following property: If $a, b, n$ are positive integers such that $ \gcd(a+i, b+j)>1 $ for all $ i, j\in\{0, 1,\ldots, n\} $ then

$$ \min\{a, b\}>c^n\cdot n^{\frac{n}{2}}$$

I've reduced this to the following problem:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_k^2} \leq \frac{1}{2} $$ where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime. How do I proceed from here?

(Numerical estimation says that the sum is about 0.45, so it would be quite a tight bound).

Comment: You can estimate the size of the $n$-th prime: to the first order, it is $n \ln n$. Alternatively, you can group all primes by size, and estimate how many there are of each size.

Comment: Can you comment on how you reduced the problem to that? As for your question, the sum is given by $$\displaystyle \sum_{n > 0} \mu (n) \frac{\log (\zeta (2n))}{n} \approx 0.4522 \cdots$$ http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared

Comment: I counted the number of primes greater than $n$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one approach:

Note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_k^2} \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{p_i^2} + 
\int_{p_k -1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{p_i^2} + \frac{1}{p_k - 1}.$$

Since $1/(p_k - 1)\to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, and since the sum is strictly $< 1/2$,
we see that taking $k$ large enough we will be able to make the RHS less than $1/2$.
In fact, taking $p_k = 17$ seems to do the job (if I didn't miscalculate).